# Issue in Map Reduce IOException

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to look for a particular string in a text file and counts of that particular string and I wrote following code and now I am not sure what I should change here kindly reply:

> Error: 16/04/29 04:30:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job
>   job_1461630807194_0010 running in uber
>   mode : false 16/04/29 04:30:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
>   16/04/29 04:34:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0% 16/04/29
>   04:34:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :
>   attempt_1461630807194_0010_m_000
>   000_0, Status : FAILED Error:  java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in
>   key from map: expected org.apache.h
>   adoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java 
>   :1072)

Here is the code:

My Mapper Class:

```
package Receipt;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class ReceiptMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>
{

    public static class Stringmap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String str = value.toString();

            String findStr = "not created";
            int lastIndex = 0;
            int count = 0;
            while (lastIndex != -1) {

                lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr, lastIndex);

                if (lastIndex != -1) {
                    count++;
                    lastIndex += findStr.length();

                }
            }
            if (str.contains(findStr)) {
                context.write(new Text(findStr), new IntWritable(count));
            }

        }
    }
}





public class ReceiptReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> 
{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) 
        {
            sum += val.get();
        }    
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}





public class ReceiptCount {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException{ {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Stringfound");

        job.setJarByClass(ReceiptCount.class);

        job.setMapperClass(ReceiptMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(ReceiptReducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);

        job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        //setMapOutputKeyClass();

        //setMapOutputValueClass();
        Path outputDir = new Path( args[1] );
        outputDir.getFileSystem( conf ).delete( outputDir, true );
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath( job, outputDir );

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure where I am going wrong it's all that I tried IntWritable and LongWritable but not able to get through with this.          And MapReduce is new for me.

Comment: My objective is to find a string in a text file which is separated by "."     for example text file is like "abc.def.naha.gsgsfs.not created" so I am trying to search how many not created are there.

Answer (score 0):

while you start with

```
public class ReceiptMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text ....
```

you are doing a

```
context.write(new Text(findStr), new IntWritable(count));
```

A long is not a string so your mapper fails.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.......... What should be there to overcome this................... I tried keeping Text as well but that didn't work.